# Amazon SNS with Firebase iOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I have integrated AWS SNS with Firebase to send Push Notifications to iOS and Android.

Everything works fine for Android, but iOS is giving me headaches. On my development device (iPhone SE), running in development mode, the notifications are always received. But when the app is installed via App Store (production), the notifications never show up, on any device. Also, after trying to send a push, the SNS Endpoint gets disabled, and for the next attempts to send it, i get the error Endpoint Disabled. I have already checked the certificates and everything seems ok.

- App iOS is configured at firebase with the APNS Auth Key (.p8)
- Notifications sent via Firebase Message Test are delivered, what makes me think that the problem is not with apple certificates.

The delivery status log says
{ ... error: NotRegistered }

Comment: Can you try upload with .12 certificate on Firebase for both development and production?

Comment: I did try it. Same behavior :/

Comment: You can try too, update pod Firebase then uninstall and install app again.

Comment: what do you mean by update pod? the package or the info inside it?

Comment: when i change certificate in firebase i have to change something in the xcode build?

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured out the solution.

I did not know that, after updating the certificates and keys in the app store developer, I had to build a new version of the app for applying these updates.

So, I reviewed all the info related to the certificates and the push notifications. When I was sure that everything was correctly configured, I build the IPA and uploaded it for Test Flight.

Now its working as it should =)